# Java generic <Something>

Tags: java, generics

I would like to know what is the meaning of those two lines in <>.

```
LinkedList<? extends SomeClass> x;
LinkedList<Class<?extends SomeClass>> x;
```

Comment: see here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell it provides for additional code re-use and eliminates the need for type casting. See the java trail for a [guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html).

The easiest way to think of it is as something you can use in code as a placeholder where the code can be more general than some specific type, and can therefor be more re-usable.

The `something` in between the brackets is meant to be a type parameter which can be substituted for any type for which it is constrained. In the case of just `something`, it could be any type, but in the case you provide in your question of `? extends SomeClass` it is constrained to types of either `SomeClass` or any subclasses of `SomeClass`.

**IMPORTANT**: the type information provided between the `<>` is erased at runtime (called `type-erasure`) so there are some limitations on how it is used, for example this will not work:

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Dog>();
```

where `Dog` is a subclass of `Animal`. Something like this is possible with regular arrays however, where the type information is still known at runtime, and putting something other than a `Dog` type will result in an `ArrayStoreException`

Comment: Thanks for such a nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<? extends Object> ls2 = new LinkedList<Number>();
```

This means that the compiler will allow you to assign the colletion to all the possible unknown subtypes of Object. Since you have the operation add, the compiler denies to give you green light, because it doesn't know if the provided object's type meets the restriction to be of the unknown subtype of Object. This is called covariance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!